# How do I get Checkstyle CustomImportOrder to work with Android Studio properly?

Tags: android, android-studio, intellij-idea, import, checkstyle

I'm seeing a lot of checkstyle import order violations
when I utilize the Android Studio's auto import or optimize import tool.

Examples being:

```
Wrong lexicographical order for 'coil.Coil' import. Should be before 'java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit'.
```

```
Wrong lexicographical order for 'androidx.annotation.Nullable' import. Should be before 'java.util.Collections.emptyList'.
```

```
Wrong lexicographical order for 'java.util.Map' import. Should be before 'org.json.JSONObject'.
```

Why does Android Studio automatically place coil after java but place org before java packages? Is there a way that I can customize the Android Studio behavior, or even better, have a checkstyle configuration that fits the Android Studio behavior?

Answer (score 0):

You can check the Android Studio setting in:

```
Preferences>Editor>Code Style>Java
```

The default of my Android Studio (Arctic Fox 2020.3.1 Patch 3) is the following:
[image]

As you can see, there are a few packages that Android Studio is treating differently. This is why the import sequence is not quite what you expected.

You can utilize the `special` group of the `CustomImportOrder`

```
<module name="CustomImportOrder">
  <property name="sortImportsInGroupAlphabetically" value="true"/>
  <property name="separateLineBetweenGroups" value="true"/>
  <property name="customImportOrderRules" value="STATIC###SPECIAL_IMPORTS###STANDARD_JAVA_PACKAGE###THIRD_PARTY_PACKAGE"/>
  <property name="specialImportsRegExp" value="^(android|androidx|com|junit|net|org)\."/>
</module>
```

Note: The static imports might still suffer the same issue but I don't think there is an option to fix this with checkstyle.